# Create a Line Dynamically Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

I want to create a underline dynamically in the UI.I have tried but i am not able to do that please help me

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/depart_details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flight_depart_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:src="@drawable/f1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/depart_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flight_depart_image"
        android:text=" XX:XX"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/depart_airport_city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/depart_time"
        android:text=" XXXX XXXX"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/depart_airport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/depart_airport_city"
        android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
        android:text=" XXXX XXXX XXXXX"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And how i am infalting it

```
for(int i = 0;i<2;i++){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.sector_details, depart_arrivals_details, false);
        depart_arrivals_details.addView(layout, i);
        }
```

I have my shape_line

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke 
        android:width="1dp" 
        android:color="#d3d3d3"/>
    <size 
        android:height="1dp" />
     <solid 
         android:color="#FFF"/>
  </shape>
```

But i am not getting how i will add this on each time the layout gets infalted.

Comment: Where you are using your `shape_line` xml ?

Comment: i have to add line as separator between the layout that i am inflating through the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this you don't have to do any thing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/depart_details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flight_depart_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:src="@drawable/f1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/depart_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flight_depart_image"
        android:text=" XX:XX"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/depart_airport_city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/depart_time"
        android:text=" XXXX XXXX"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/depart_airport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/depart_airport_city"
        android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
        android:text=" XXXX XXXX XXXXX"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/depart_airport"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="#d3d3d3" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: let me try this @gaurav